# InnoDB Transaction Help - Select then if Not Found Add Unique Row

Tags: design-patterns, transactions, innodb

I have a mysql table that contains IPAddress parts

```
TABLE `EndPoints`(
    `EndPointId` BIGINT(19) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `IpPart1` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `IpPart2` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `IpPart3` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `IpPart4` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`EndPointId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

---

Each `IpPart` contains the byte of an IPAddress byte array.
e.g. address **100.101.102.103**
IpPart1 = 101;
IpPart2 = 102;
IpPart3 = 103;
IpPart4 = 104;

---

**Anyway!**

I want to do the following :

```
SELECT EndPointId FROM EndPoints WHERE
    IpPart1 = @a AND
    IpPart2 = @b AND
    IpPart3 = @c AND
    IpPart4 = @d;
```

Then, if the address is not found, add it

```
INSERT INTO EndPoints (IpPart1,IpPart2,IpPart3,IpPart4)
    Values(@a,@b,@c,@d);
```

---

**Using MySql transactions how will I ensure that only one row is added for each IPAddress?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you *could* BEGIN a transaction, do the two queries you quoted, then COMMIT. But wouldn't it be easier just to put a UNIQUE key over (IpPart1, IpPart2, IpPart3, IpPart4)?

(Is there really anything to be gained by separating out the octets in this way? It seems unlikely you'd want to eg. search on and index IpPart3 alone. IPv4 addresses are often stored as a string or simple integer converted by [inet_aton](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton). IPv6 addresses are a bit more work, using a canonicalised string or a BINARY char(16).)

Comment: thanks bobince, yeah I know it is strange, but i want be be able to map ip classes etc.  How would you go about the transaction?  I think I would have to do a non locked select.  If not there, lock the table with IsolationLevel.Serializable (which I think locks the table) then perform a select again! - to see if it has just been inserted, then if still not there, perform the insert.. commit... am I on the right track?

Comment: Since the query is based on row existence you can't get away with a simple `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, but there are other ways than a full table lock (which is in generally to be avoided). With a `UNIQUE` constraint on the compound IpParts index it would be as simple as doing the INSERT on its own then catching and ignoring the exception if it was already there. Or, using MySQL-specific syntax, `INSERT IGNORE`.